# Ruby gem 'pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)', is not available in the local ruby installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

This is the error i face when try `bundle install` in the terminal. I will want to keep my Ruby version as it is.

```
Bundler found conflicting requirements for the Ruby  version:
  In Gemfile:
    Ruby  (~> 2.7.1.0)

    capybara (>= 2.15) was resolved to 3.32.2, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.8) was resolved to 1.10.9, which depends on
        Ruby  (< 2.7.dev, >= 2.3) x64-mingw32

Ruby  (< 2.7.dev, >= 2.3), which is required by gem 'pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)', is
not available in the local ruby installation
```

how should i solve this?

Comment: Your `Gemfile` contains an incompatible set of dependencies. How did you end up in that state? What are you trying to achieve? There's also no such thing as ruby version `2.7.1.0`. Perhaps [you meant `2.7.1`](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/)?

Comment: i am not sure why it is 2.7.1.0 either. This is in my gem file ```source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.1'

gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]```

I am trying to run a ruby project from github but I am unable to do so

Comment: If you have a complete `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` that you could share, then please add it to your post. If you're trying to run an open-source project, then why not link to it in your post? If you've made any edits to any files, then could you also share that in your post. All of this information is much easier to read if you [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63578774/edit) instead of trying to squeeze it here in the comments section.